# JWT passport auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, passport.js

I'm using the following code to create a JWT web-token:

```
 function generateToken(req, user) {
     const ONE_WEEK = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
  return jwt.sign(user, config.auth.jwtExtraSecret, {
    expiresIn: ONE_WEEK
  }) // secret is defined in the environment variable JWT_SECRET

}
```

Then when it comes to send data to the client i do the following code

```
 res.send({
        user: sendData(user, 'username','tokens','_id', 'extraToken'),
        extraToken: generateToken(req, userJson),

        })
```

Note: that extraToken is not attached directly to the user model, and i **dont** want it to be attached there. There is another token that is assigned to the user model (permanent token) and it works good when authenticating routes. 
*(so please restrain yourself from giving advice on that)*

The purpose of the extraToken is to have an expiration date.

> For passport strategy

```
 let options = {

   jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
   secretOrKey: config.auth.jwtExtraSecret
  }



 passport.use(
    new JwtStrategy(options, async function (jwtPayload, done) {
       try {
        const user = await User.findOne({_id: jwtPayload._id})

     if (!user) {
       return done(new Error(), false)
     }
     return done(null, user)
    } catch (err) {
     console.log('error here in catch')
     return done(new Error(), false)
   }
 })
)
```

For assessing

```
     jwtAuthCheck(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('jwt', function (error, user) {

        if (error || !user) {
            res.status(403).send({
                message: 'you dont have an access'
            })

        } else {

            req.user = user
            next();

        }


    })(req, res, next)
},
```

When sending request to the route in my header

```
as a key i have "Authorization" and as a value ~Bearer ${token}~
```

> **THE PROBLEM and THE QUESTION**

By some reason it keeps giving me a message

```
  "message": "you dont have an access"
```

The error begins in a catch statement in passport.use, not sure what i'm doing wrong. Please help, have been on this problem for very long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns nothing:

```
function generateToken(req, user) {
    var token = jwt.sign({
        user,
        auth: 'magic',
        agent: req.headers['user-agent'],
        exp: Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60
    }, config.auth.jwtExtraSecret);

    return token;
}
```

Your header should be `Authorization`, not `Authorisation`.

Comment: I've changed the header to Authorization, i've noticed it just a few mins ago. That function that u said above DOES in fact return a token, i've checked it multiple times, i've also change that function for the sake of simplicity at the moment

Comment: I've tried to put const user = await User.findOne({_id: jwtPayload._id}) in my catch error statement and it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined" which is weird coz i use findOne in other routes and it works normally

Comment: Did you define your User model in your route file? Did you include mongoose?

Comment: I rechecked, and u were right. Instead of importing User i imported {User} :(